# How do I view the HTTP-protocol records after applying the pre-master secret?

Tags: debugging, https, wireshark

I'm trying to debug a problem with some HTTPS requests that the Firefox developer tools are sending (specifically, the source maps - if I turn on "Show original sources" I get a 404 error instead of JS source).

I've captured some HTTPS logs with dumpcap + firefox + SSLKEYLOGFILE, but now it feels like the tools are falling apart.

[image]

I've got the decrypted SSL data, but the content is gzipped! I can't read this!

How do I get Wireshark to parse the decoded SSL data as an HTTP stream?

Answer (score 0):

The *Follow SSL Stream* option is a generic SSL dissector feature that displays the raw contents of SSL plaintext data. In your capture, the HTTP response body is compressed, but that is completely opaque to the SSL dissector.

Wireshark can decompress the compressed HTTP response body, be sure to enable it at *Preferences* -> *Protocols* -> *HTTP* -> *Uncompress entity bodies*. After that, there will be a *Uncompressed entity body* tab on the bottom of the byte view in the main window.